# Input instructions and print them out in reverse order using ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have to input a few instructions and print them out in reverse order. I can only input one instruction and output one at the same time.

```
public class ReturningHome {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

String direction;
String Street;


    while (true){
        System.out.println("Enter instructions from Home to School");
        System.out.println("Please input instructions in the format:"
                + "\nDirections: [L/R]"
                + "\nStreet Name: [Street Name]");
        System.out.println("The final instruction should be SCHOOL");

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Enter a Direction");
        direction = TextIO.getlnString();
        switch (direction){
        case "L": 
            System.out.println("Enter a Street Name");
            Street = TextIO.getlnString();
            switch (Street){
            case "SCHOOL": 
                System.out.println("Instructions from School to Home:");
                System.out.println("Turn RIGHT into your HOME");
                System.exit(0);

                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Instructions from School to Home:");
                System.out.println("Turn RIGHT onto "+Street+ " Street");
                System.out.println("");
                break;
            }
            break;

        case "R":
            System.out.println("Enter a Street Name");
            Street = TextIO.getlnString();
            switch (Street){
            case "SCHOOL":
                System.out.println("Instructions from School to Home:");
                System.out.println("Turn LEFT into your HOME");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Instructions from School to Home:");
                System.out.println("Turn LEFT onto "+Street+ " Street");
                System.out.println("");
                break;
            }

            break;


            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Choice");
                break;

        }       
    }
}
}
```

How can I do this using an `ArrayList`?

Comment: No. My bad i didn't mean to put that

Comment: :) You can edit your question.

Comment: You could add each instruction to the ArrayList as it is entered; then at the end, you could traverse the ArrayList in reverse order and print each instruction you find.

Comment: "I can only input 1 instruction and output 1 at the same time." Is that not good? How is it supposed to work?

Comment: i have to input at least 2 instructions and output them in the opposite direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
public class Instructions {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Print instructions...

        List<String> instructionsList = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = null;

        while (true) {

            do {
                System.out.println("Enter a direction");
                input = scanner.next();
            } while (!input.matches("L|R"));
            instructionsList.add(input);

            System.out.println("Enter a street name");
            input = scanner.next();
            if (input.matches("SCHOOL"))
                break;
            instructionsList.add(input);
        }

        scanner.close();

        System.out.print("From SCHOOL ");
        for (int i = instructionsList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if ((instructionsList.size() - i)%2 == 1)
                System.out.printf("turn %s to%n", instructionsList.get(i));
            else
                System.out.printf("%s, then ", instructionsList.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("HOME");
    }
}
```

You can add an arbitrary number of instructions to the list. I also formatted the output a bit, but it's not necessary.

Comment: @user3670479 Because you didn't import it.